# Symbolic solution of first order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

Is it possible to get simbolical solution of this differential equation:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(x_0x_1) = -\dfrac{8}{r_i-z(r_i-1)}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} x_0}{\mathrm{d}z} $$
where if $z=1: x_0=1, x_1=0$.
I tried to solve it like this, but it does not work:

```
sol = DSolve[
  x1'[z] == (-8 * x0'[z]/(ri - z (ri - 1)) - x0'[z]*x1[z])/x0[z], x1, 
  z]
```

I tried to integrate it by hand, but I am making some mistakes because I can see that the numerical and my solution are different (probably something between $\mathrm{d}z$ and $r_i-z(r_i-1)$).

Comment: Condition `x1==0` and use inside `DSolve` as function `x1[z]` are contradictory!

Comment: Why is contradictory?

Comment: You use the same symbol as parameter and function!

Comment: Do you mean z is the same symbol as parameter and function? Or some other symbol?

Comment: Your initial conditions should be written as `x0[1] == 1, x1[1] == 0`; however, you have two functions with only one equation. Your system is underdetermined.

Comment: Ok, I will not use x0[1] == 1 (that is for equation before this one, from the same system), I will just use x1[1] == 0.

Comment: The number of initial conditions does not change the number of equations that relate `x0[z]` and `x1[z]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumig you want solve the TeXform of the equation:

Integrate both sides

```
x0[z]x1[z]-x0[1]x1[1]== -Integrate[-8 /(ri - zz (ri - 1)) x0'[zz],{zz,1,z}]
```

Knowing `x1[1]==0` it follows

```
x1[z]== -Integrate[-8 /(ri - zz (ri - 1)) x0'[zz],{zz,1,z}]/x0[z]
```

Comment: Yes, but Mathematica does not give solution, in solution it just write Integrate, or integral symbol.

Comment: That's true, Mathematica provides a form for arbitrary function `x0[z]`

Comment: Well, I have x0[z], it is x0[z] = (1 + 64 beta (1 - 1/(ri - z (ri - 1))^3)/(3 (ri - 1)))^0.5. Now your x0[z]x1[z]==c-Integrate[-8 /(ri - z (ri - 1)) x0'[z],z]   gives me soluton with Hypergepmetric function, so it probably means it is not so easy to integrate this by hand, as I thought?

Comment: What do you know about parameter `ri` and `beta`? Are there singularities of the integrand?

Comment: ri and beta are not dependent on z, they are constants.

Comment: That's clear: To evalate the integral you need to know wether there are singularities of the integrand inside the intergation range z. Examplary `ri - z (ri - 1)==0` or something similar.

Comment: I know the range of z and ri, z takes values between 0 and 1 (it is z coordinate), and ri is constant with values between 0.7 and 1.3 (ri take one value between this boundaries). According to that, there is no singularity inside the integration range z.